# SNMP4J-Agent: SampleAgent vs TestAgent

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

The documentation of ***SNMP4J-Agent*** tells, if you want to write your own SNMP agent you should sub-class ***BaseAgent***. 
And this is done in ***TestAgent*** class in the **org.snmp4j.agent.test** package.

But in  **org.snmp4j.agent.example**  there is another class ***SampleAgent*** which doesn't derive BaseAgent but, still implements an agent. 
Could anyone tell me the difference between these two implementations?
And also in order to write your own agent, which is the better code to learn from.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally!! found the answer in [this](http://oosnmp.net/pipermail/snmp4j/2009-January/003330.html) mailing list..

Comment: Good to summarize info from your link, as explained at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: The link is broken